# How to Fix this Bad Operand (&&)

Tags: java

I'm pretty new at coding and need some help with this. I am not 100% sure on what a bad operand is and have no knowledge on how to fix this.

**My Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//String.phrase;  Scannerobject.next();
  int count = 0;

  Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  String in = in1.nextLine();
  in = in.trim();
  for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++){
    if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' && in.charAt(i + 1));
  }

  // more work here

  System.out.println(count);
  count++;
}
}
```

**Error**

```
exit status 1
Main.java:12: error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
    if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' && in.charAt(i + 1));
                            ^
first type:  boolean
second type: char
1 error
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: A "bad operand" is an operand of a type that the operator can't handle.  For `&&` a "bad operand" is one that isn't of type `boolean`.  `in.charAt(i + 1)` is of type `char`, not of type `boolean`. What were you trying to say with `if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' && in.charAt(i + 1))`?

Answer (score 4):

Both sides of the expression must yield to a `boolean` result.

```
if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' && in.charAt(i + 1));
                           ^^This will not evaluate to either true or false
```

I think you wanted

```
if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' && in.charAt(i + 1) == ' ')
```

Also note that there is no semi colon after the `if`.

---

If you are trying to count the number of words, you want to iterate over the length of the `String` and every time there is a white space, add to the counter. So something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++){
    if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

However there are also a lot of easier ways to do this. Utilizing the `split()` method you can do:

```
System.out.println(in.split(" ").length);
```

Which will split the inputted `String` on a whitespace, and then find the length of the resulting `Array`

Comment: I totally forgot to add what I was going for in the explanation. This helped fixed my code, but it keeps giving the number 0 once I type in a sentence like "hello world"

How do I get the code to say the number of words in the sentence?